# Operations between pairs of columns in R

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I have a dataset like this:

```
set.seed(123)
spring_2000 <- runif(15, 270, 330)
spring_2001 <- runif(15, 270, 330)
spring_2002 <- runif(15, 270, 330)
winter_2000 <- runif(15, 4, 60)
winter_2001 <- runif(15, 4, 60)
winter_2002 <- runif(15, 4, 60)

df_spring <- data.frame(spring_2000=spring_2000,
             spring_2001=spring_2001,
             spring_2002=spring_2002)

df_winter <- data.frame(winter_2000=winter_2000,
                    winter_2001=winter_2001,
                    winter_2002=winter_2002)

df <- cbind(df_winter, df_spring)
```

I want to apply this function to all pairs of columns corresponding to spring and winter of the same year:

```
subtraction <- function(x,y){
  x+(365-y)
}
```

where x is winter_2000 and y is spring_2000, then x is winter_2001 and y is spring_2001, etc. and of course I want to do it quickly and efficiently for the all pairs of columns in the dataset. I am struggling with this.

The expected output is a dataframe made of three columns (one column per year, i.e. 2000, 2001, and 2002), with values corresponding to winter_2000+(365-spring_2000) for the first column, winter_2001+(365-spring_2001) for the second column, winter_2001+(365-spring_2001) for the third column.

Comment: Maybe `group_by` and do some mapping? Could you add a glimpse of your expected values? Also `spring_2000` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  gather(Year,Value,contains("winter")) %>% 
  gather(Year_1,Value_1,contains("spring")) %>% 
 group_by(Year,Year_1) %>% 
  mutate(Target=Value_1 + (365-Value))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's pretty close to what I expect. This code gets to match all potential pairs, while I only need winter2000+(365-spring2000), winter2001+(365-spring2001), winter2002+(365-spring2002).